# Homomorphic image of an irreducible representation

Tags: representation-theory

Let $H$ be a group. Let $V$ be any representation of $H$ and let $\sigma$ be an irreducible representation of $H$. Let $\varphi \in \text{Hom}_H(\sigma,V)$. I keep reading that the homomorphic image of an irreducible representation (such as in this case) is either an irreducible representation or $\{0\}$. Why? I understand that the $H$-action is preserved but why is irreduciblity  guaranteed?

Comment: I think we briefly talked about this in my course in rep theory. I think this is an appeal to Schur's lemma but maybe someone else can chime in.

Comment: Have u checked Shur's lemma?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The kernel of a morphism between representations is an invariant subspace, so if the domain is irreducible, it's either the whole space (then the image is trivial) or zero (then the morphism is an isomorphism onto its image, so the image is irreducible).

This shows also, that an endomorphism of an irreducible representation is invertible, if it's not zero, so the endomorphism ring is a division algebra and hence, if you are over the reals and have a finite dimensional representation, the space of endomorphism is isomorphic to the real, the complex numbers or the quatornials by a theorem of frobenius.